# PostgreSQL doesn't pull up where condition before joins

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, logstash

I have a Logstash pipeline ingesting data from a PostgreSQL into Elasticsearch.
PostgreSQL version is 11.21.
The index is a combination of data from different tables, so the query is something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  table1.col1,
  table1.col2,

  ... 
  table8.coln
FROM
  table1
  LEFT JOIN table2.table1_id = table1.table1_id
  ...
  LEFT JOIN table8.table1_id = table1.table1_id
WHERE
(
  table1.updated_on > :sql_last_value
  OR
  table2.updated_on > :sql_last_value
  ...
)
ORDER BY table1.table1_id DESC
```

The updated_on fields all have a BTree index attached.

The query is run every minute, and the expected number of rows to update in that timeframe is a few dozens.

However, the execution time of this query is between 5 and 10 seconds.
Looking at the plan, this is due to the fact that the planner doesn't take advantage of the indexes, and performs Paralled Seq Scan on many of the tables, joins them, and only after filters the rows.

However, i can force to use the indexes like this:

```sql
WITH table1 AS (
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE updated_on > :sql_lat_value
)
<rest of the query
```

Since the CTE returns a few rows, all of the JOINs are run on that subset and the query runs in < 10ms.

However, i feel like something is off, since this seems like a trivial optimization to me (pull up the where condition on the relations before executing the joins; even more trivial since the where conditions are on indexed fields).
The query also is pretty linear, without subqueries or other complexity.
There could be some specific reason or configuration causing this?

This is likely happening on other queries in the system and it would be a pain to go and optimize each query by hand.

Comment: You could try moving the relevant part of the WHERE clause to each JOIN clause e.g. LEFT JOIN table2.table1_id = table1.table1_id AND table2.updated_on > :sql_last_value

Comment: No index can be used here. Are you sure that the join between `table1` and `table2` has to be an outer join?

Comment: @NickW that is working! In fact, now it is filtering also on table1 before the joins and using the index. The table1 condition remained in the WHERE clause. So was I wrong to assume that this query would be simple enough for the optimizer? At this point i might always go with filtering directly on the join condition

Comment: Nothing to do with simple or not: the semantics are different. It's impossible for the optimizer to transform it to mean something else other than what is intended.

Comment: Ok, after analyzing better the situation and the question that has been attached to this, I think i've wrapped my head around it. Thank you!

Comment: The optimizer was sort of following what you were suggesting. You created joins that pulled back all candidate records and then in your WHERE clause you were filtering out those records you didn't need. By moving the logic to the JOIN you are only pulling back the actual records you want from the joined table